# Variables To Text Files

Tags: python

I'm really new to Python and I am trying to write to a text file with user input, I'm getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tvanderb/PycharmProjects/Text Files/Add Writing.py", line 3, in <module>
    import _io.TextIOWrapper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_io.TextIOWrapper'; '_io' is not a package
```

I have tried importing `_io.TextIOWrapper` and `_string` but it doesn't do anything. What I mean by user input is I ask for a string of text then I put it into a  variable and write the variable to a text file.
Here's my code:

```
text = input("Enter Text: ")


with open('File2.txt', 'w') as x:

   file_contents = text;

   x.write(x + '\n')

   #print(x, file=x)
   #print("\n", file=x)
   #print(file_contents, file=x)
```

I just found out how to do what I wanted to do:

```
text = input("Enter Text: ")


with open('File2.txt', 'r') as x:
     file = x.read()

with open('File2.txt', 'w') as x:
   if file == '':
      x.write(text)

   else:
      x.write(file + '\n')
      x.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't used the `io` and `string` packages at all; you can remove those lines.

Second, you're trying to write a file descriptor into the output file.  Perhaps you mean

```
with open('File2.txt', 'w') as x:
   x.write(text + '\n')
```

Do those help your confusion?

Comment: Yes it did. I wanted to write the file and the user input so that it would just add the text I figured it out in my second edit.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the standard library very easily like so:

```
text_to_write=input('Type text here:')
with open('myfile.txt','w') as file:
     file.write(text+'\n')
```

Comment: Using `with open` means you should *not* close the file afterwards. That is handled automatically.